# How to show the existence of a subgroup of an abelian group??

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If an abelian group has subgroups of orders m and n, respectively, then show that it has a subgroup whose order is the least common multiple of m and n.

I tried solving this on assumption that if an abelian group has a subgroup of order, say, N then it has an element whose order is also N. This leads me to the point where I arrive at two different elements having orders m and n as in the question, whereby I obtain a third element whose order is the l.c.m of m and n.

Now, was my assumption correct in the first place?? If it's wrong, please let me know and help me get this solution right.

Comment: No your assumption is wrong. Your assumption would mean that all finite abelian groups are cyclic, which is clearly false.. Note that the subgroup generated by your two subgroups is finite and has order divisible by both $m$ and $n$. Also the converse of Lagrange's Theorem holds for abelian groups.

Comment: @Derek Holt. Point taken...thank you. But if the abelian group was infinite, the converse of Lagrange's Theorem won't help, would it?

Comment: I added something to my answer to take care of the case where $G$ is infinite.

Comment: The subgroup generated by two finite subgroups of an abelian group is always finite, even if the group itself is infinite, so you can apply the converse of Lagrange's Theorem to that finite subgroup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $H_0$ and $H_1$ be subgroups of size $m,n$ and let $H_2=H_0\cup H_1=\{h_1,h_2\dots h_s\}$ and suppose the elements have orders $o_1,o_2\dots o_s$ respectively .Then the set $H_3=\{h_1^{e_1}h_2^{e_2}\dots h_2^{e_s}| e_1,e_2\dots e_s\in \mathbb Z\}$ is a subgroup, because $G$ is abelian. It is also finite as it has at most $o_1o_2\dots o_s$ elements.

By Lagrange's theorem $m$ and $n$ divide $|H_3|$, so $lcm(m,n)$ divides $|H_3|$, so by the following lemma $H$ has a subgroup of order $lcm(m,n)$ (Notice $H_3$ is clearly abelian also).

Lemma: Let $G$ be a finite abelian group and $d$ a divisor of $|G|$, then $G$ has a subgroup of order $d$ (in other words, every abelian group is a converse lagrange group).

Proof:

The proof is by strong induction over $n$

If $|G|=1$ it is trivial. The inductive case is as follows:

If $d=1$ it is trivial, otherwise take $p$ a prime that divides $d$. By cauchy's theorem there is a subgroup $N$ of order $p$, because $G$ is abelian $N$ is normal, so we can consider the canonical projection $\varphi:G\rightarrow \frac{G}{N}$.

Now notice that $d/p$ divides the order of $\frac{G}{N}$, so by the induction hypothesis there is a subgroup $K\leq \frac{G}{N}$ of order $d/p$.

Consider the subgroup $H=\varphi^{-1}(K)$ what is it's order ? Consider the restriction of $\varphi$ to $H$, the kernel is $N$ and the image is $K$, we conclude $\frac{H}{N}\cong K$, so $H$ has order $p\frac{d}{p}=d$.

We have found a subgroup of order $d$.

Comment: very elegant proof. Thank you. But how about the case when the abelian group is infinite??

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The assumption was that there are *subgroups* of orders $m$ and $n$, not *elements* of orders $m$ and $n$.

Comment: You are completely right, I have fixed it.

Comment: @DerekHolt is it ok now?

Comment: Yes it's OK now, And the proof does not assume that $G$ is finite. You are applying the lemma to the finite subgroup $H_3$, not to $G$.

Comment: yeah, exactly! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your assumption that our group has an element of order $N$ is not always true- the converse of Lagrange's theorem does not always hold. Also just because an element $g^N=e$ doesnt mean it has order N either (e.g. could have order $N/2$).

Firstly, for my solution it useful to show that

if $g \in G$ has order $n$, then $g^{k}$ has order $\dfrac{n}{(n,k)}$ for any $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ (1)

First we prove the special case when $m$ and $n$ are positive integers such that $(m,n)=1$:

The required element of $G$ is $xy$ and the least common multiple in this special case where $(m,n)=1$ is $mn$. Let $\left\vert xy \right\vert = c$ then we will show that $c = mn$ as required.

Since $(xy)^{m} = y^{m}$ has order $n$ according to (1) and also we have $n \mid c$. Likewise, applying the same argument, since $(xy)^{n}= x^{n}$ has order $m$ we have $m \mid c$. Therefore, we have $mn \mid c$ because $(m,n)=1$. Furthermore, since $(xy)^{mn} = e$ we have $c \mid mn$ and hence equality $c=mn$, proving the special case where $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime.

Now we are ready to prove the exercise for the general case. Let's reiterate the conditions and statement: Suppose $x,y \in G$, $\left\vert x \right\vert = m$,$\left\vert y \right\vert = n$ and $xy=yx$ then there exists an element in $G$ of order $[m,n]$, the least common multiple of $m$ and $n$. Let's write out $m$ and $n$:
$$m = p_{1}^{\alpha_{1}}p_{2}^{\alpha_{2}} \cdots p_{k}^{\alpha_{k}}$$
$$n = p_{1}^{\beta_{1}}p_{2}^{\beta_{2}} \cdots p_{k}^{\beta_{k}}$$

so $[m,n] = p_{1}^{max\{\alpha_{1},\beta_{1}\}}p_{2}^{max\{\alpha_{2},\beta_{2}\}} \cdots p_{k}^{max\{\alpha_{k},\beta_{k}\}}$. Clearly, $max\{\alpha_{i},\beta_{i}\} = \alpha_{i}$ or $\beta_{i}$.

If $max\{\alpha_{i},\beta_{i}\} = \alpha_{i}$ then by (1) we know the order of $x^{\frac{m}{p_{i}^{\alpha_{i}}}}$ is  $\dfrac{m}{(m,\frac{m}{p_{i}^{\alpha_{i}}})} = p_{i}^{\alpha_{i}}$. Likewise, if $max\{\alpha_{i},\beta_{i}\} = \beta_{i}$ then by (1) we know the order of $y^{\frac{n}{p_{i}^{\beta_{i}}}}$ is  $\dfrac{n}{(n,\frac{n}{p_{i}^{\beta_{i}}})} = p_{i}^{\beta_{i}}$. Therefore, for every $1 \le i \le k$ there exists element $z_{i}$ such that $\left\vert z_{i} \right\vert = p_{i}^{max\{\alpha_{i},\beta_{i}\}}$ where $z_{i}$ is some power of $x$ or $y$ and since $xy=yx$ we have $z_{i}z_{j}=z_{j}z_{i}$ for all $1 \le i \le j \le k$. Hence, by the Special Case, since distinct $z_{i}$ have orders which are mutually relatively prime we have $\left\vert z_{1}z_{2} \cdots z_{k} \right\vert = p_{1}^{max\{\alpha_{1},\beta_{1}\}}p_{2}^{max\{\alpha_{2},\beta_{2}\}} \cdots p_{k}^{max\{\alpha_{k},\beta_{k}\}} = [m,n]$ as desired.

Comment: Thank you, Robert C. It's rigourous, and I love mathematical rigour.

Comment: @krishna2016 No problem :) Although it's not the fastest method Im glad it was useful.

Answer (score 0):

Let $U$ and $V$ be the subgroups of order $m$ and $n$ respectively, where the prime decomposition of $m$ and $n$ is given by, 
$$
m = \prod_{i=1}^K p_i^{\alpha_i}\:\: 
\text{and}\:\: 
n = \prod_{j=1}^L p_j^{\beta_j}
$$

For any prime $p$  such that $p|m$ or $p|n$ or both, consider the maximum power of $p$ that divides either $m$ or $n$ or both,   let that be $\gamma(p)$. Let $S$ be set of all such primes. Then,
$$lcm(m,n) = \prod _{p \in S} p^{\gamma(p)}$$

For any  $ p \in S$, there will be a corrsponding  p-syllow  subgroup either in $U$ or $V$ or both, let that subgroup be $H_p$ and $o(H_p) = p^{\gamma(p)}$. Now the desired subgroup of order $lcm(m,n)$ is direct product of all such $H_p$,
$$H = \prod _{p\in S} H_p$$